# What is the default value of django's model field options ``blank`` and ``null`` when they're not set?

Tags: django, django-models

In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/), I was not able to find an answer to this.

If I want a field to be left blank, do I have to explicitly set `blank=True` ?

EDIT: I'm blind. Or stupid. Thanks for pointing that out to me ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know you've linked the docs, but I'm putting this out explicitly for anyone that comes across the same question.  The answer to your headline question is explicitly and clearly there in the docs, though - both are `False` by default.  If you want the field to be `blank=True`, then yes, you'll need to manually specify on every field.

Blank is for Forms:

> If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is False.
>
> Note that this is different than null. null is purely
>   database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has
>   blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a
>   field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Null is what is stored the Database if you save a record with nothing in that field. Again, the field attribute for this is `null=False`

> If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database. Default is False.
>
> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty
>   strings, not as NULL. If a string-based field has null=True, that
>   means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty
>   string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for
>   “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL.
>
> For both string-based and non-string-based fields, you will also need
>   to set blank=True if you wish to permit empty values in forms, as the
>   null parameter only affects database storage (see blank).

There are plenty of occasions when you'd want the form to be blank, but the database entry to be `not Null` - if for example, [you were specifying your own custom slug on model save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401230/auto-generated-slugs-in-django-admin/42402548#42402548).

This also means, of course, that any custom `Field`s you derive from the main `Field` class will have the same default behaviour.  If that really bothers you, you could override the [Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field) class with your desired behaviour, but that would be really janky to debug for the others who come after you.

Comment: "_Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty strings, not as NULL_". I'd like to understand better this sentence. She is meaning that I'd be better to avoid using `null=True`, because if I want to allow saving "no data" values in a string-based field, it's simply to save the empty string?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you can have both Null  and `''` as values for no data.   If you leave `null=False` for these fields and do not save a value to them, then the value is automatically `''`, an empty string.